# SharePoint 2013 Themes vs Master Pages with CSS Only

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, css, theme

For display purposes I changed to a Composed Looks for my Master Page. When I changed back to a Master Page that was using only CSS not Themes, I still had remnants of the theme, background-image and some colors were changed like the "Getting started with this site web part".

I tried a couple of ways to reset some of the theme stuff as follows:

```
body{
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BackgroundOverlay",opacity:"0.5")] */ background-color: white;
        /* [ReplaceBGImage] */ background-image: none;

        border-top: solid black 15px;
    }
```

Also I changed my Master Page from using a link to CSSRegistration and put my code in "Style Library/en-us/Themeable".

Nothing seems to work. The page is using some theme stuff and non-theme stuff?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

By change to the "Composed Look" of Office, I was able to reset my master page. I would still like to know how to theme-proof my Master Page CSS deployments. It seems whether you choose to use themes or not they are used.